# Why does IE10 Mobile render my in-canvas PNG incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, html5-canvas

I'm using a "mask" image as an input, draw it to a canvas, then use getImageData to detect the colour of pixels.

This works perfectly under Safari, Chrome, Firefox, their mobile versions, and Android's stock Browser. It also works in IE11 (the only version I currently have as a Virtual Machine).

Under IE10 Mobile, its display is completely wrong.

I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tDLL/1/) to demonstrate the problem. On a compatible browser, it should show two grids. The first is white and red (red is the mask colour I chose), and the second is the processed version; black and white.

Like so:

[image: Correctly Rendered Example]

However, IE10 Mobile on Windows Phone 8 renders it completely wrong, sort-of like this:

[image: IE10 Mobile Incorrectly Rendered Example]

(Ignore the JPEG artifacts, that's a side effect of sharing a screenshot).

The actual drawing code is extremely simple:

```
var source = document.createElement('canvas');
source.width = this.width;
source.height = this.height;
source.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
body.appendChild(source);
```

As you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tDLL/1/), I've attempted to disable image smoothing in a variety of ways without success. Does anybody know why this doesn't work, and how to fix it?

Comment: Comment to say that I've just grabbed IE10 Win 8 from http://modern.ie and that does *not* exhibit this bug. Only IE10 Mobile.